# Tener varios proyectos en laravel en un servidor?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de subir mi proyecto en laravel a mi servidor vps. No sé como gestionar varios proyectos en el servidor web apache.

Mi estructura de directorios es `/var/www/html ...` Según leí en tutoríales, dice que hay que dejar el proyecto antes de la carpeta que es pública (en mi caso html) de esta forma quedó con `/var/www/proyecto_laravel..` pero no tengo idea de como mostrar la parte publica, en realidad estoy un poco perdido.

Lo que no quiero es dejar todo mi proyecto laravel en la carpeta html, ya que se exponen los archivos de configuración.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro, la idea siempre es proteger los archivos del acceso publico. Lo más recomendable es tener un usuario dedicado del servidor que gestione tu página web. Cuando creas el usuario el servidor te genera la siguiente estructura:

```
/home/miUsuarioNuevo/
```

Bien, cuando ahora te vos depositar tu proyecto dentro de esa carpeta quedanto la siguiente estructura:

```
/home/miUsuarioNuevo/composer.json
/home/miUsuarioNuevo/app/
/home/miUsuarioNuevo/public/
```

El siguiente paso es crear un [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) en tu `httpd.conf` que apunte a tu carpeta pública del proyecto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/miUsuarioNuevo/public
ServerName www.mi-sitio-en-laravel.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Nótese como apache ahora va a servir tu página web de laravel en `/home/miUsuarioNuevo/public`, y el resto de tu proyecto queda protegido del acceso público.

**La otra solución**  es mantener su ambiente de trabajo sobre `/var/www/html` tal y como es por defecto. En este caso tendrías que poner tu proyecto en `/var/www/` quedando la siguiente estructura:

```
/var/www/composer.json
/var/www/app/
/var/www/public/
```

Finalmente editas el archivo `httpd.conf` para que el acceso público cambie de `/var/www/html` a `/var/www/public/`. De esta forma apache solo mostrara el contenido público en dicha carpeta.

> Nota! Antes de editar el archivo `httpd.conf` haz una copia de seguridad `cp httpd.conf httpd.conf.bk`. Asi editar el archivo con total libertad y haciendo pruebas.

Comment: muchas gracias !  en realidad no es tan difícil crear virtualhost. nunca lo había modificado y como lo muestras es muy sencillo. Gracias

Comment: Buenísimo! Me alegra que le haya servido.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos, una versión más fácil de montar tu proyecto laravel en un servidor es haciéndolo de la siguiente manera;

**1)** Colocas tu proyecto laravel fuera de la carpeta **/html_public** del servidor que seria **/home/tu_proyecto**.

**2)** Corta o copia el contenido de la carpeta **/tuproyecto_laravel/public**  que contiene la carpeta donde está tu proyecto laravel y pégalo en la carpeta **/home/html_public** o como se llame en tu servidor.

[image: Contenido de la carpeta /public]

**3)** Configura el archivo index.php que has pegado dentro de la carpeta **/home/html_public**, así como se puede visualizar en la siguiente imagen, `require DIR.'/../tu_proyecto/bootstrap/autoload.php';` donde dice `/tu_proyecto` solo tienes que poner el nombre de la carpeta de tu proyecto que colocaste fuera de la carpeta pública del servidor, y en la siguiente línea tambíen tienes que configurarla de la misma manera, osea, en la parte done dice `$app = require_once__DIR__.'/../tu_proyecto/bootstrap/app.php';` igual nuevamente donde dice /tu_proyecto vuelves a poner el nombre de la carpeta de tu aplicación laravel.

[image: Archivo index.php]

Comment: en realidad esa era la que ya tenía, pero necesitaba agregar más de un proyecto en laravel. es por eso mejor la configuración de virtualhost

Comment: Exacto, si es para tener varios proyecto, se recomiendo la virtualización de dominio como dice el compañero @manix